# Flutter - Change default font "undefined name context"

Tags: flutter

I'am trying to change the default font theme of the app, but it gives me an error that says:

> undefined name 'context'.
>   Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

The error in this line `Theme.of(context).textTheme,` here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:nazar_mob/app_base/animations.dart';
import 'package:nazar_mob/pages/second_page.dart';
import 'package:nazar_mob/app_base/app_bar.dart';

void main() {
runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoCondensedTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        ),
    ),
    home: new MyFirstPage(),
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        "/MySecondPage": (BuildContext context) => new MySecondPage()
    },
    )
);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose your MaterialApp inside a Widget. The widgets (stateless or stateful) provide a `build` function, that gives you a `context`:

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoCondensedTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        ),
      ),
      home: new MyFirstPage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        "/MySecondPage": (BuildContext context) => new MySecondPage()
      },
    );
  }
}
```